# Call to undefined function ctools_ajax_text_button()

Tags: 7, views, javascript, chaos-tool-suite

What I need is a link to click and open a form in a modal.

Call to undefined function ctools_ajax_text_button() in ctools\includes\modal.inc on line 184

This is how I'm calling the function in hook_page_build() function.

```
ctools_include('modal');
ctools_modal_add_js();

$links[] = ctools_modal_text_button(t('Modal Login'), 'modal_forms/nojs/login', t('Login via modal'));
```

Also tried bellow:

```
$test = ctools_modal_text_button('Test Link', 'node/123', 'alt here', 'no-class');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add ajax :)

```
ctools_include('modal');
```

**ctools_include('ajax');**

```
ctools_modal_add_js();
```